# NameError: name functionName is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

My startup file

```
from UserInfo import UserInfo

user = UserInfo()
print(user.username)
```

UserInfo.py file

```
from fileinput import filename

class UserInfo(object):
    """description of class"""

    username = "";
    password = "";

    def readConfig(fileName):
        config_file = open(filename,"r")
        username = config_file.readline()
        password = config_file.readline()

    def __init__(self):
        readConfig("config.txt")
```

Exception: `NameError: name 'readConfig' is not defined`

Why readConfig function is not accessible in the same class?

Comment: Yes, there is no local or global variable called `readConfig`. I suggest reading a couple of tutorials about classes in Python. It is clear that you are coming from a language with a different model. e.g., you're not explicitly referencing `self` (which is necessary in python) and you are creating useless class-level variables (i.e. static variables) that you are going to immediately shadow in your initializer. And perhaps most telling, you are using semi-colons....

Comment: to refer the method in the same class, you need `self.readConfig` and the arguments of readConfig should be `readConfig(self, fileName)`

Comment: Why use trailing semicolons? Also, there seems to be a typo in "fileName" / "filename"

Comment: @ThomasWeller He's probably coming from the perspective of a Java-ish language. Look at how he's defining his instance attributes in the class statement.

Comment: As @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, the variable should belong to the instance instead of the class. So it should be declared in `__init__` and prefixed with `self.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some stuff missing in your implementation:

```
class UserInfo(object):
    """description of class"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.username = ""
        self.password = ""
        self.readConfig("config.txt")

    def readConfig(self, fileName):
        config_file = open(filename,"r")
        self.username = config_file.readline()
        self.password = config_file.readline()
```

The first is your should qualify `self.readConfig` in the `__init__` method. Also, in all instance methods, the first parameter must be `self` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the instance of the class. Try the following code snippet:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.readConfig("config.txt")
```

Comment: Won't work unless you make `readConfig` an instance method, as in another answer.